# as any as customeType

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, angular5

I was studying the the [latest angular code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/worker/main.ts) which is in typescript and came to the following line:

```
const scope = self as any as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

What I don't understand about above is: if the type self is any why would you cast it as  ServiceWorkerGlobalScope? Why wouldn't you just declare it as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope like the following:

```
const scope = self as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
```

or

```
const scope : ServiceWorkerGlobalScope = self;
```

What does that line mean? Does it mean scope is of type any which most like to be of type ServiceWorkerGlobalScope?

Comment: This is because `self` has certainly a type that does not have the same "form" as `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. So, they uses `any` to have a "formless" object and then use `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the simplified:

```
const scope : ServiceWorkerGlobalScope = self;
```

TypeScript will check the strucutre of `self` against the type `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. If it finds the types to be incompatible you'll receive an error along the lines of:

> Type 'Window' cannot be converted to type 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope'.
>     Property '...' is missing in type 'Window'.

By moving `self` into the `any` type first, the check is then performed between the `any` type and the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` type. In this case, `any` is compatible with "any" other type and there are no warnings.

This is the same flow that applies to type assertions, you can attempt a type assertion:

```
x = <ServiceWorkerGlobalScope>y
```

But a type assertion still performs type checking. If you want to "opt out" of type checking, you use the `any` type as an intermediary:

```
x = <ServiceWorkerGlobalScope><any>y
```